# pandas read_csv: ignore trailing lines with empty data

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to read the following data from a csv file:

```
id;type;start;end
Test;OIS;01/07/2016;01/07/2018
;;;
;;;
```

However, pandas read_csv will try reading the empty lines `;;;` as well. Is there a way to automatically ignore these trailing lines of empty data?

These lines are causing a problem because I am using `read_csv` with `converters`, and the functions in the converters will dutifully throw an exception when they encounter invalid data, meaning I don't even arrive at a valid dataframe. I could change the functions to convert invalid data to `NaN` and then drop `NaN`s from the dataframe, but then I would silently be dropping erroneous data as well as those empty lines.

Some clarifications:

- The lines of empty data will always been trailing, it's a common problem with csv files generated from Excel.
- The data is user-generated so manually cleaning the file is not an option.

Comment: From the docs: "`skip_blank_lines`: whether to skip over blank lines rather than interpreting them as NaN values" as an attribute for `read_csv()`. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Comment: `skip_blank_lines` defaults to `True` so it should have been skipping blank lines. I assume this option refers to truly blank lines as opposed to lines containing the delimiter only.

Comment: @Anne have you ever found a way? I'm having the exact same problem (except in my case the number of empty ;;; rows in unpredictable)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure you can so it directly with read_csv but you can use dropna:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv("in.csv", delimiter=";")
df.dropna(how="all", inplace=True) 
print(df)
```

Comment: One way would be to simply clean the file yourself removing the trailing ;;;;, Also `df.dropna(how="all"..` would only drop lines that had all nans. What do you want to do with the invalid data?

Comment: For this particular file of course I could, but this data is supposed to be passed in by various users, and I think it would be user-friendly if they didn't have to go check their files for trailing lines. That's why I am looking for an automatic solution.

Comment: For the invalid data I really want to be throwing an exception... I don't think it's going to be a good idea to handle the case of trailing lines in the converter functions by converting the data to NaN.

Comment: Well you could still do an inplace filter before creating the dataframe, it would not matter where the data came from. You could also do a single pass over the file and find the line num that has the first `;;;;..` then use `skip_footer=line_number`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82086/discussion-between-anne-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 0):

`panda.read_csv( skip_blank_lines=True )` will skip lines that are only NaN

Version: Pandas v1.5

Answer (score -2):

If you know that you want to ignore the last 2 lines then you can pass param `skipfooter=2`:

```
In [197]:
t="""id;type;start;end
Test;OIS;01/07/2016;01/07/2018
;;;
;;;"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';', skipfooter=2)
df

Out[197]:
     id type       start         end
0  Test  OIS  01/07/2016  01/07/2018
```